# Make an alias work in "that" directory? Even if created in .zshrc

Tags: zsh, find, alias, pwd

This is zsh but perhaps applies to other shells.

Say you are in directory `/foo` and you

`% find $PWD -name '.*'`

it works fine, results are from `/foo`.

Now (in `/foo`) type this

`% alias crazy="find $PWD -name '.*'"`

Now go `% crazy` and you'll see the same result. All good.

But. Say in (example) Mac, put in your `.zshrc`

```
# Let's see what happens:
% alias crazy="find $PWD -name '.*'"
```

Now, for example on the Mac, open a new Terminal session. In the Mac *nix case, it does that, opening the zsh in some particular default directory, in fact `/blah/fattie` .

Now `% cd /foo` and enter `crazy`

In fact. The results you get are the results from `/blah/fattie` .

If you want "crazy" to work as expected, you have to, essentially, do this

`% alias crazy="find $PWD -name '.*'"`

again in `/foo` and then it will operate on "that" directory ie `/foo`

Is there a solution to make

`% alias crazy="find $PWD -name '.*'"`

work in the **"directory it is in now"** rather than "the directory it was in when the alias was made"?

Comment: In your example you could just replace `$PWD` with `.`.

Comment: @mpy find behaves subtly differently re dot files in that case unfortunately, hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the solution is simple, thanks to use Kamil

Wrong

```
% alias crazy="find $PWD -name '.*'"
```

Correct:

```
% alias crazy="find \$PWD -name '.*'"
```